# In Spider-Man's story line, is there any other newspaper except the Daily Bugle?

Tags: marvel, spider-man

In all Spider-Man related canons that I have read or watched, the only newspaper seen is the Daily Bugle. Since all these canons revolve around Peter Parker, it is justified to have the highest priority for the Daily Bugle.

I always wondered, isn't any other newspaper interested in Spider-Man's stories? With Peter Parker snapping so many great pictures of Spider-Man, no other competitor of the Daily Bugle ever tried to hire him? With Jameson's über-sarcasm any employee would have quit working under him, but still Parker works for him and that too after being underpaid most of the time.

In one animated series, Jameson is running his own news channel with himself as news reporter. This news channel is always being shown on screen at Times Square in which Jameson is running anti-Spider-Man rants.

Isn't there any other newspaper in Spider-Man's city?

Comment: Spiderman is set in a fictionalised New York city. From what I can recall, their main competitors are **real newspapers** like the NYT and Sun

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The main rival of the Daily Bugle, excluding real newspapers like the New York Times and New York Sun (which are referred to but never seen) is the [Daily Globe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daily_Globe_%28comics%29), introduced in Amazing Spider-Man #27 (August, 1965).

[image]

As the wikipedia article notes, the Globe is invariably used as a foil for the Daily Bugle, publishing articles that the Bugle refuses to run (such as that [Matt Murdock is the Daredevil](http://www.theothermurdockpapers.com/2014/02/review-daredevil-36/) for which they get sued) and providing an alternate place for Bugle employees to work, something which Peter does in [Spider Man : Marvel Adventures #2](http://www.spiderfan.org/comics/title/marvel_adventures.html#002) and then again in [Spider Man #203](http://marvel.wikia.com/The_Spectacular_Spider-Man_Vol_1_203)

[image]

Comment: So...why didn't Parker stay on with the Globe?  It seems like he gets treated better just from that one panel.

Comment: @Zibbobz - I honestly have no idea. JJ comes back a couple of issues later (after having recovered from his nervous breakdown). I'm assuming Peter gets headhunted back. Give me a few minutes to have a read through the next few issues.

Comment: @Zibbobz - Ok. In issue 208, they announce that the Globe has a new owner who thinks the paper has been too focused on printing facts, not stories. Peter gets demoted to co-head photographer. In issue 210, it turns out the the boss is in league with Madame Web to try to steal the deeds to the Globe, the paper suspends publication and Peter gets a call from JJ offering him his job back.